# How to limit the speed of my Mobile Hotspot on my Windows 10 PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

So, recently i have started to set up my computer as a mobile hotspot for my mobile phones, the issue is, my internet speed ON the pc goes down to like 7-8 Mbps from the usual 800-850 Mbps when the hotspot is activated, how do i limit the hotspot so that the connected devices are allowed to use maximum of 10-20 Mbps and im left with the rest for my own use on my pc?

Comment: It's not possible with windows on-board tools, you'll need to install additional software (either a software router or a software firewall that will manage the traffic).